# Get Different Base Url using Javascript in Development and Production Site

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using javascript to get base url using this code:

```
alert(window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host);
```

It will display http://localhost:[port_number] in development site. Then, after deploy to production site, it will display http://dev01

It gives me wrong base url, since the home url is http://dev01/WebApplication1. I can add the application name in the code, so it will be:

```
alert(window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/WebApplication1");
```

but this method is not practical, because I have to remove `"/WebApplication1"` when in development site.

Is there any workaround for this case?

Comment: You should probably use relative urls if you're not requesting resource from other domains.

Comment: what's your server side language? PHP or C#?

Comment: @Neverever C# ASP.NET MVC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do this from server side.

The `WebApplication1` will change depends on your IIS virtual directory setting

To have the code **working for both** Development & Production environemnt

Try the following.

in **Layout.cshtml**

```
<head>
    <script>
        var base_url = '@Request.Url.GetComponents(UriComponents.SchemeAndServer, UriFormat.Unescaped)@Request.ApplicationPath'

        // navigate around the site, base url should be the same
        alert(base_url);
    </script>
</head>
```

Comment: Thanks @Neverever, I think this is what I want.

Answer (score 4):

Can you simply add some conditional logic to append the subdirectory in production?

```
var host = window.location.host,
    path = host === 'dev01' ? '/WebApplication1' : '',
    fullPath = window.location.protocol + '//' + host + path;

alert(fullPath);
```

Comment: It works, but I think the drawback is there is hard-coded inside. Thanks @benjarwar

Answer (score 0):

Try following code it may work:

```
    var patharray=window.location.pathname.split("/");
    alert(window.location.origin+"/"+patharray[1]);
```

Here window.location.path will give you full path of your site...